# What do I need to do to make IPv6 devices globally accessible using Uverse 6rd?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, ipv6

**Summary:** With UVerse's 6rd implementation, do I need to buy/install/configure a compatible wireless router in the DMZ to properly handle the IPv6 traffic in both directions (incoming connections too)? Am I missing obvious settings on my end? Or, is UVerse only halfway implementing IPv6, and there is nothing I can do until (if?!?) they finish implementing it?

### Details

I enabled the new option on my Residential Gateway (2Wire 3801HGV with firmware 6.11.1.29-enh.tm) to enable IPv6. The DHCPv6 option is greyed out, overriding (with Firefox developer tools) it does nothing. I then put DHCPv6 back to disabled. All my computers and Raspberry Pi are receiving IPv6 addresses based on their MAC address and the global IPv4 of my RG (Residential Gateway). From what I read, this is SLAAC auto configuration, and AT&T delivers the IPv6 via 6rd.

All my devices can reach out to the IPv6 internet and read/access/download. However, I do not seem to be able to ping or portscan those IPv6 addresses. I have tried disabling "Block Ping" on the RG, and I have tried configuring "pinholes" for the firewall. The "pinholes"/rules work for IPv4, but not IPv6.

At the moment, I am not sure if the RG is not routing incoming IPv6 connections, or if it is, but that they firewall is not knowing how to handle it. It may be possible that I need to put my own router (I don't have one) in the DMZ and configure it to allocate and route IPv6 traffic.

I can and always have been able to access home devices globally over IPv4 by opening/forwarding a "pinhole" in the firewall and then using what my current global IPv4 address is. I am attempting to do the same, but now over IPv6. Dynamic DNS services have always made it so static IPs are not needed for personal use.

Note that IPv6 tunnels of all kind were blocked/broken prior to UVerse enabling IPv6. Therefore, installing a tunnel is not a possible work around.

### Further information

The RG (Residential Gateway) reports:

`Default Gateway:        2602:300:c533:1510::1
6rd BR:                 12.83.49.81
6rd Prefix:             2602:300::/28
6rd Delegated Prefix:   2602:306:bcf7:JJJJ::/60
6rd MTU                 1472`

The Linux desktop reports (H,J,Q-T,V-X replace numbers for security):

`wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:d0:HH:HH:HH:HH
          inet addr:192.168.1.71  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2602:306:bcf7:JJJJ:QQQQ:RRRR:SSS:TTTT/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2602:306:bcf7:JJJJ:2d0:VVVV:WWWW:XXXX/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::2d0:VVVV:WWWW:XXXX/64 Scope:Link`

The Windows Laptop reports (J,K-N,Y,Z replace numbers for security):

`IPv6Address:       2602:306:bcf7:JJJJ:KKKK:LLLL:MMMM:NNN
Link-local IPv6:   fe80::KKKK:LLLL:MMMM:NNN%11
IPv6 Gateway:      fe80::bae6:25ff:YYYY:ZZZZ%11
IPv6 DNS Server:   <blank>`

Comment: You definitely need ipv6 support in your *main* router and for it to be set up approrpriately.

Comment: I think it would be fair to call 6rd "halfway implementing IPv6". They'll eventually have to do it right. And while it shouldn't affect end users very much... You have probably just run into a limitation of the 2wire device.

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure it's the piece of crap 2wire. Have AT&T switch it out for a Motorola NVG589.